# Any way to declare routing strategy for an WPF element?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Suppose we have a WPF element, for instance StackPanel with Buttons, Textboxes etc. inside.
Is there any way to say directly in XAML that I want a tunneling strategy?

```
<StackPanel RoutinStrategy="Tunneling" ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - the strategy is defined at the event level. By convention, events prefixed with "Preview" are tunneling, whilst their counterparts are bubbling.

Comment: Ok thank you! That means that i have to define my custom event. Am I right?

Comment: You haven't really told us what you're doing :) If you want to define your own RoutedEvent, you pass the strategy in when you create it via the EventManager.

Comment: Ok thank you. I think that those Preview events should be enough for me. Didn't know that. Thanks once more.